# How to know AVSpeechSynthesizer speech finish in iOS objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have play pdf file text-to-speech.  I have a converted pdf to string page by page. Add all page string in NSMutableArray(EX:- 150 pages pdf , add first index - first page string ). How to get the first page string is over and speaking finish ?. And speak second page string ? I have searched in Google but I didn't find anything. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to think about page unit.
You have to think about utterance. 
Any amount of text you send to the speakUtterance method, 
and AVSpeechSynthesizer finishes speaking, 
the following delegate method called.

speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer 
 didFinishSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance;

So inside the delegate method, you have to call speakUtterance method again.

But in usual case, a few words or sentences(normally one sentence) will be sent to AVSpeechSynthesizer. == call speakUtterance
Then if speaking finishes, inside the delegate method, logic begins to start next sentence or word.

It's all I can tell you.